# CustomAction Called Twice

Tags: c#, wix

I use Wix, and have a customAction and a anb installSequence:

```
 <CustomAction Id='PreInstallAction' BinaryKey='PreInstallBinary' DllEntry='MyCustomAction1' Execute='immediate'
                  Return='check'/>
      <Binary Id='PreInstallBinary' SourceFile='E:\...\MyCustomAction\bin\Release\MyCustomAction.CA.dll'/>

      <InstallExecuteSequence>
         <Custom Action='PreInstallAction' Before='InstallInitialize'/>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

**The problem is that my custom action is called twice** - (In the custom action I print things into the log file and I see them twice)

I tried to comment the line:

```
 <MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no" AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" DowngradeErrorMessage="Can't downgrade from newer version"  />
```

And it solved the problem.
But I need the major update so I tried uncomment the above line and add a condition to the customAction:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
         <Custom Action='PreInstallAction' Before='InstallInitialize'>
            NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH
         </Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But now ny customAction is called twice again...
Is anything wrong with my condition? I s there any other solution?

Comment: By twice do you mean once during the old version uninstall and another during the new version install?

Answer (score 6):

Your custom action is executing twice because it's in the execute sequence of both the new and old install.  When RemoveExistingProducts performs the major upgrade it's actually running the uninstall of your old product so both come into scope.  You could fix this by placing a conditional expression on the sequencing of the custom action so that it only runs during uninstall of the old or the install of the new.

Also, depending on what this CA is actually doing, Immeadiate execution scheduling may not be the best option.  Any custom action that changes the state of the machine must be scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize with Deferred ( usually System Context ) Execution to ensure propert rights and rollback behavior ( you have to author the rollback and commit actions also ).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, custom actions are called twice when you upgrade, because they are executed both on install and uninstall. (when you upgrade, both an install and an uninstall event occur.)

To solve this, you need to say "if I am upgrading, then this action must not also be executed on uninstall". This can be written logically as

```
upgrading => not uninstall
```

, which (since A ⇒ B  ⇔  ¬A ∨ B) can be rewritten as

```
(not upgrading) OR (not uninstall)
```

So the condition to write in WIX is:

```
<Custom Action="PreInstallAction" Before="InstallInitialize">
      (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE ) OR (NOT ( REMOVE="ALL"))</Custom>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Custom Action CustomActionUpgrade who's purpose is to save files from the previous installation before uninstalling the software and installing the newer version during MajorUpgrade. (Archiving previous installation)

Write your Custom Action like this to call it only once, and only during an upgrade before the previous installation is uninstalled:

```
<Custom 
  Action='CustomActionUpgrade'
  Before='RemoveFiles'>UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE AND REMOVE~="ALL" AND NOT REINSTALL="ALL"
</Custom>
```